# Laravel Validation Passing Blank Input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a laravel form to update existing user's information in the database, but if a field in that form is blank, I don't want it to update that record in the database. As it is now, if the field is blank and the form is submitted, it passes that blank input and removes the record in the database.

Below is the function to edit the user's information and then perform the database update. I currently attach the Request::old('...') to the email, but since the validation on that is 'unique:users', it gives the error 'email is taken'.

Thanks,

```
public function postEdit(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'unique:users|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'min:6',
        'confirm_password' => 'same:password', 
        'about_me' => 'max:500',
    ]);

    Auth::user()->update([


        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        'confirm_password' => bcrypt($request->input('confirm_password')),
        'about_me' => $request->input('about_me'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('profile.edit')->with('info', 'You have updated your profile!');
}
```

Comment: If the user deletes the information, then it means he wants the field to be blank. No?

Comment: Well, they need an email address in the system. So, the options would be to (1) make the field required, but have validation that doesn't error if that email is the same as the current database record for that user, or (2) allow the field to be blank and, if so, just keep the current database record and not set it to ' '.

Comment: Unique accepts a 3rd parameter. Pass the user id in that parameter and it will check for unique email though the the field in concerned user will be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `unique` rule to exclude the record you are editing.

Instead of

```
'email' => 'unique:users|email|max:255',
```

you should use:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email,'. Auth::user()->id.'|email|max:255',
```

[Reference for unique rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an "except" in the validation rules and didn't see it was listed under the "unique".

Answer (score 0):

In validation rules you can set 'required', and this must help.

Comment: Right, but the issue is if that field is required, and the user wants to keep that email the same, then it'll return an error as the email is already taken.

Comment: I see 2 options in this case. 
1) Remove unique rule from validator and check this manual way.
2) In this case user must be authorized. Write another rule, which will combine unique rule, and check if authorized user email same as input.